# Vue Loader images in node modules third party css are not resolved

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm using webpack to build my vue.js app, and everything is fine until images are found into imported a node_module css file. 
They cannot be resolved.

```
<style lang="less">
  @import '~@vue/vue';
</style>
```

where in vue.less

```
@import (inline) "@{node_modules}/third_party_lib/unmodifiable.css";
```

Can't resolve `'./my_image.png'`

Adding `url=false` to `vue-loader` is an option

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    extractCSS: prod,
    loaders: {
      less: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader?url=false!less-loader',
    },
  },
},
```

but it breaks the ExtractTextPlugin...

How can I tell vue-loader to look in the right folder?
Or, how can I tell webpack to, please, don't try to resolve images path as modules at all ?

Comment: Could you share where its looking fo those images vs. where they are? Also, to be clear: this only happens in the prod build? dev server runs fine and shows the images? What's the config for the loade that loads image s(file-loader / url-loader)?

Comment: Maybe the `alias` option of css-loader can help you? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#alias

Comment: I would test with alias @LinusBorg, in the meanwhile, as I'm not interested in resolving images as modules by webpack, I've found a quicker solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not interested to resolve my images as modules by webpack I've found that this extra option in loader is a quick win.

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    extractCSS: prod,
    loaders: {
      less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader?url=false!less-loader',
      }),
    },
  },
},
```